# Use FFmpeg to generate a movie with alpha channel from separate video and fill movies?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, alpha

I have two movies: input_v.mp4 and input_k.mp4. input_v is the video fill, input_k is a black and white matte for keying.

I want to use FFmpeg to create output.mov in the Avid DNXHD codec, with input_v as the fill (RGB) video and the alpha (A) built from the luma values of input_k.

Is this possible?

Comment: The planes can be combined but ffmpeg's DNX encoders don't support alpha. ProRes does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking for a movie format showing as a matte effect in Avid then this might work:

```
ffmpeg -i input_v.mp4 -i input_k.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]alphamerge" -shortest -c:v qtrle -an output.mov
```

As [mulvya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/mulvya) suggests Prores also supports an alpha channel.