# FFMPEG DNxHR with Alpha to Webm

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, blackmagic-fusion

I'm trying to convert a video file exported from `Blackmagic Fusion` as DNxHR with Alpha checked to WebM or PNG. FFMPEG seems to ignore the alpha and the background is black. Is there something I need to do? This is what I'm currently using:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.5 -i DNxHR444A.mov -vframes 1 test.png
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i DNxHR444A.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 test.webm
```

I can upload my test video if that helps. But it's quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg's DNXHD/R decoder does not support [alpha](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3707). Either use another codec  on export, or export alpha separately (it will be a grayscale picture). With the 2nd method, ffmpeg can combine the main image and the alpha for onward processing.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get it working using your suggestion and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46937409/313272