# ffmpeg transparent HVEC video from alpha matte and color video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-toolbox

I have an alpha.mp4 (alpha matte video) and a color.mp4 (color video). How do I use ffmpeg to make a transparent HVEC (.mov) video?

I can combine with ffmpeg to make a .webm file following the instruction here:
https://www.unscreen.com/api under "Convert unpacked Pro Bundle to WEBM video with transparency"

I have a newer mac and should be able to use HVEC_videotoolbox from either these 2 videos or the .webm file created.

The closest I found was this which seems to generate a corrupt video that cannot be viewed in safari. [Use FFmpeg to generate a movie with alpha channel from separate video and fill movies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916778/use-ffmpeg-to-generate-a-movie-with-alpha-channel-from-separate-video-and-fill-m) but

Comment: Take a look at my comments to the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542326/4926757). It is base on the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61663438/4926757). The example is "over complicated": `ffmpeg -y -i edited.mp4 -i matte.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=320x240 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:240,setsar=1:1,split[vs][alpha];[0:v][vs]alphamerge[vt];[2:v][vt]overlay=shortest=1[rgb];[rgb][alpha]alphamerge" -shortest -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.75 -vtag hvc1 -pix_fmt yuva420p -an output.mov`

Comment: Thanks for your response Rotem. Ideally the pixel dimensions don't need to specified. But even changing it 720x1280 for my test video returns this error on a mac:

Comment: Incompatible pixel format 'yuva420p' for codec 'hevc_videotoolbox', auto-selecting format 'bgra'
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ffmpeg -y -i color.mp4 -i alpha.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=720x1280

Comment: Running "ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_videotoolbox" gives me: 
Supported pixel formats: videotoolbox_vld nv12 yuv420p bgra p010le

Comment: I can't help you, because I don't have a Mac for testing... Maybe you can ask Alex, be adding comment below the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70540761/4926757). It could be a version issue. Note, that this is not a programming question. I think the question better fits Super User community site.